# How to Properly Feed the Result of One Function Into Another Function

Tags: r

I have a list containing telemetry objects of annual animal tracking data. I'd like to create a function to calculate MCP home range estimates for each individual within each annual telemetry object

Currently, I have two functions set up. The first creates a list of spatial coordinate dataframes for each individual, which is necessary to calculate MCP home ranges. My second function is supposed to use the list of spatial coordinate dataframes to calculate MCP home range estimates, however it only results in two MCP calculations for each of the two annual datasets (there should be 4 in the first telemetry object and 2 in the second one). I think the problem might have to do with how I'm subsetting the buffalo.sp spatial object within the MCP function (buffalo.sp_list[[i]][[i]]), but I'm not sure how to correctly feed the spatial points data into the MCP function. Any ideas?

```
library(ctmm) 
library(ggplot2) 
library(dplyr) 
library(stringr) 
library(lubridate) 
library(sf) 
library(tidyverse) 
library(sp) 
library(scales) 
library(tidyr) 
library(tibble)

#Load the data
data("buffalo")

#Creating individual dataframes and adding an id column
Cilla <- as.data.frame(buffalo$Cilla) 
Cilla$id<-"Cilla"

Gabs<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Gabs)
Gabs$id<-"Gabs"

Mvubu<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Mvubu)
Mvubu$id<-"Mvubu"

Pepper<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Pepper)
Pepper$id<-"Pepper"

Queen<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Queen)
Queen$id<-"Queen"

Toni<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Toni)
Toni$id<-"Toni"

#Combining dataframes and adding a year, UTM zone, and date column
buffalo2 <- rbind(Cilla,Gabs,Mvubu,Pepper,Queen,Toni)
buffalo2$Year<-year(buffalo2$timestamp)
buffalo2$Year<-as.factor(buffalo2$Year)
buffalo2$UTM.zone<-"12 +datum=NAD27"
buffalo2$timestamp <- ymd_hms(buffalo2$timestamp) 
buffalo2$Timestamp<-buffalo2$timestamp
buffalo2 <- separate(buffalo2, timestamp, c("date","time"), sep= " ", remove= TRUE, extra= "merge")

#Reordering columns
buffalo2 <- buffalo2[, c(8,9,1,2,6,7,11,10)]

#Splitting data by year
data2005<-buffalo2 %>% 
  filter(Year==2005)
data2006<-buffalo2 %>% 
  filter(Year==2006)

#Creating annual telemetry data
Tdata2005<-as.telemetry(data2005, timeformat="auto",timezone="UTC", 
                        timeout=Inf,datum="NAD27",
                        na.rm="row",mark.rm=FALSE,keep=FALSE,drop=FALSE)
Tdata2006<-as.telemetry(data2006, timeformat="auto",timezone="UTC", 
                        timeout=Inf,datum="NAD27",
                        na.rm="row",mark.rm=FALSE,keep=FALSE,drop=FALSE)

#Creating a list of telemetry data
Tdata<-list(Tdata2005,Tdata2006)
names(Tdata)<-c("Tdata2005","Tdata2006")

#Load adehabitat package
library(adehabitatHR)

#creating a function that will make a list of coordinate dataframes for each individual
buffalo.sp <- function(x, date) {
  buffalo.sp_data <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {  
    X<-x[[i]][[5]]
    Y<-x[[i]][[6]]
    ID<-names(x)
    XY <- data.frame(X, Y)
    buffalo.sp_data[[i]]<-data.frame(ID[[i]],X,Y)
    coordinates(buffalo.sp_data[[i]]) <- c('X', 'Y')
  }
  return(buffalo.sp_data)
}

#Applying the buffalo.sp function to the list of dataframes with dates
buffalo.sp_list<-lapply(seq_along(Tdata), function(i) buffalo.sp(Tdata[[i]], Years[i]))

# adding names
for (i in 1:length(buffalo.sp_list)) {    
  names(buffalo.sp_list)<-names(Tdata)
  names(buffalo.sp_list[[i]])<-names(Tdata[[i]])
}

#creating a function that will make a list of coordinate dataframes for each individual
MCP <- function(x, date) {
  MCP <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(buffalo.sp_list)){
    MCP[[i]]<-mcp(buffalo.sp_list[[i]][[i]], percent=95)
  }
  return(MCP)
}

#Applying the MCP function to the list of dataframes with dates
MCP_list<-lapply(seq_along(Tdata), function(i) MCP(Tdata[[i]], Years[i]))

# adding names
for (i in 1:length(MCP_list)) {    
  names(MCP_list)<-names(Tdata)
  names(MCP_list[[i]])<-names(Tdata[[i]])
}
```

Comment: Your question is long and complex rather than minimal and reproducible.  It's unlikely to get many naswers, and may even get closed, because of that.  *We need some test data!*  Please provide some, otherwise all we can do is review your code.  The problem may not be in your code, but in your data, in which case we can't help.  Your code down to `library(adehabitatHR)`  appears to be data wrangling, and therefore probably irrelevant.  Do your datasets "look good" at that point?  if so, we don't need the code.  Just the datasets at that point.

Comment: That said, `buffalo2$Timestamp<-buffalo2$timestamp` looks odd.  It's either a mistake, or bad practice.  Similarly, returning an object named `gila.sp` from a function named `gila.sp` may not be syntactically wrong, but is certainly confusing.  It allows you to refer to the function when you mean the object and vice versa.  Personally, I'd (1) use `lapply` rather than loops: simpler code, less opportunity to make a mistake in the indexing and ...

Comment: ... (2) write one function that gave me the right answer for one source dataset (given your description, I'm not even sure what that is!) and then loop over source datasets, again, using `lapply` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I'm using buffalo tracking data built in to the ctmm package to reproduce my error since tracking data contains a lot of information that would be difficult and time consuming to manually enter. As such, I need to include the data cleaning step to get to the cleaned data I feed into my home range calculations. The reason I create a second timestamp column is...

Comment: ...so I can split it into a time and date column while still retaining the original timestamp column in the dataset. The gila.sp syntax was my mistake, I meant to change it to buffalo.sp prior to posting. I can also change the function name to be different from the object name.

Comment: You may need it: we probably don't.  Give us the results of `dput(data2005)` and `dput(Tdata2005)` (or subsets of it if they're too large), and reduce your code by at least 40 lines.  Thanks for clarifying the source of the data.  I'm not familar with `ctmn`, so I won't be contributing further.  But I repeat my first question: *Do the contents of (eg) data2005 and Tdata2005 look good?*  If yes, then the wrangling is irrelevant and the code unnecessary.  If not, then fix those problems before worrying about your `MCP` function.